# What is difference between Init-Only and ReadOnly in C# 9?

Tags: c#, properties, .net-5, readonly, c#-9.0

I am going through [C# 9 new features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/) which will be released soon. [Init-Only](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#init-only-properties) properties are being introduced with it.

The one big limitation today is that the properties have to be mutable for object initializers to work: They function by first calling the object’s constructor (the default, parameterless one in this case) and then assigning it to the property setters.

Init-only properties fix that! They introduce an init accessor that is a variant of the set accessor which can only be called during object initialization:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

**With this declaration, the client code above is still legal, but any subsequent assignment to the FirstName and LastName properties is an error.** What does this line mean? If ReadOnly also does the same thing then what is the use of an Init-Only property?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated in the new C# 9 [features post,](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/)

> The one big limitation today is that the properties have to be mutable
>   for object initializers to work: They function by first calling the
>   object’s constructor (the default, parameterless one in this case) and
>   then assigning to the property setters.

However, value types with readonly modifiers are immutable as stated in [readonly documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly).

Therefore, it is not possible to use readonly properties with object initializers.

However, with Init-only properties you can use object initializers.

Comment: Thank you, so other than this difference, both  will be same in all aspects? Or in other words can I say to use object initializer to readonlty properties they have come up with Init_Only properties?

Comment: I think this is the main reason for the implementation of this new feature but without more information about the implementation details, I am not sure.

Comment: Can you provide example which shows the difference between the two

Comment: @viveknuna Go and watch https://mybuild.microsoft.com/sessions/fc099bf7-8c85-4c3b-9a90-2d917342f945?source=schedule .

Comment: With init, Callers can use property initializer syntax to set the values, while still preserving the immutability (readonly properties).

Comment: FYI: "_types with readonly modifiers are immutable_" _Only_ as far as the C# compiler is concerned. On the IL/CLR level, readonly fields are mutable. Which actually makes them modifiable by C# source code as well, for example by mutating a readonly field through reflection...

Answer (score 15):

The purpose of Init-only properties is to allow assignment only in the object initializer or the constructor for your class.

If we consider your `Person` class, assigning to `FirstName` or `LastName` is allowed in the constructor or in the object initializer but you can't assign to `FirstName` or `LastName` in other places:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }

    // this is a constructor
    public Person()
    {
        this.FirstName = "first name"; // works
        this.LastName = "last name"; // works
    }
}

//this is a random method
public SomeMethod()
{
    Person myPerson = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "first name", // works
        LastName = "last name" // works
    };

    myPerson.FirstName = "change the first name"; // Error (CS8852)
    myPerson.LastName = "change the last name"; // Error (CS8852)
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good example though: **if** `Person`'s constructor never assigns to `LastName` and if you do `Person p = new Person() { FirstName = "bob" }` (and _never_ assign to `LastName`) then the program has unwittingly violated the `class Person`'s contract because `LastName` is now `null` despite being typed as `String` (not `String?`), which throws-off C#'s nullable-reference-type checking abilities.

Comment: @Dai I don't understand why you're saying it's not a good example, "if Person's constructor never assigns to LastName..."
Well first of all it's not the case here. Secondly, there's a second condition : having nullable enabled. And if despite all these conditions someone happens to be in the situation you described, CS8616 will let them know there's a problem

Comment: CS8616 only applies to reference-types - if you're using value-types or have `#nullable` disabled in your `.csproj`  then the compiler won't give you any warnings at all.

Comment: Well that's one more condition (and again it's not met in my example). Indeed, CS8616 won't pop, but you'll get [CS0843](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0843?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0843)). If you're disabling nullable well  nullable-reference-type checking abilities don't exist so there's no point in having CS8616.

Comment: CS0843 only applies to `struct`  types, not classes.

Comment: Yeah so you'll have CS0843 with structs and CS8616 otherwise

Comment: No, that is incorrect: CS0843 is when a `class` has unassigned non-nullable reference-type members, while CS0843 is when a `struct` has unassigned members (regardless of being reference-types or value-types), _not_ when a `class` has unassigned `struct` or other value-type members (that's when you don't get any warnings at all, which is dangerous when the `default(TValue)` a value-type is meaningful, e.g. `enum` values.

Answer (score 2):

This also prevents bloated constructors where you have a lot of optional parameters. For example, in the below class:

```
    public class InitOnlyExample
{
    private readonly string _firstName;
    private readonly string _lastName;
    private readonly string _address;
    private readonly int _zipCode;
    private readonly string _phoneNumber;

    public InitOnlyExample(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        string address,
        int zipCode = default,
        string phoneNumber = default
    )
    {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _address = address;
        _zipCode = zipCode;
        _phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public string FirstName { get { return _firstName; } }

    public string LastName { get { return _lastName; } }

    public string Address { get { return _address; } }

    public int ZipCode { get { return _zipCode; } }

    public string PhoneNumber { get { return _phoneNumber; } }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main use of init only property is to avoid constructor boiler plate that comes with using readonly/getter only properties.

Consider the following class with 2 getter only properties

```
public class Point
{
  public int X { get; }
  public int Y { get; }

  public Point(int x, int y)
  {
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
  }
 }
```

For n number of getter only properties, we will need n number of lines in constructor to initialize them. This is negligible for the class I have used here but not so for classes that has lot more getter only/readonly properties. Init only properties lets us avoid this boiler plate. [[Source]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init)

Answer (score -3):

Unlike set an init-only property can only be set in the constructor or by using a property initializer.

Comment: You answer doesn't add much value. Do you have something new to add that the other answers do not cover?