# Difference between readonly, private set, init and get only properties in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I am from Java springboot world and recently started learning C# 10 (.NET 6) for one of our clients requirement, initially I was facing a lot of pain understanding fundaments of C# 10, but now I am little comfortable, however I am not able to find good documentation, blogs or questions which provides comparison between similar features and some useful example.

I am currently trying to understand the difference between below, please also check if below is valid ?

```
public class Employee {
  public int Id {get;}; 
  public string Dept {get; set;};   
  public string FirstName {get; readonly set;}; 
  public string LastName {get; private set;}; 
  public string DateOfJoining {get; init;};
}
```

This is my guess, please review and help me understanding

```
public class Employee {
  public int Id {get;}; // hardcoded must be defined at the design time and can never change?
  public string Dept {get; set;};   //mutable - can be modified multiple times?
  public string FirstName {get; readonly set;}; // NOT SURE 
  public string LastName {get; private set;}; // NOT SURE 
  public string DateOfJoining {get; init;}; //immutable - can be set only once from constructor? 
}
```

Comment: `readonly set` is not valid.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties#access-control

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there should not be a semicolon after the properties declaration.

this `public string FirstName { get; readonly set; }` is invalid, it will give compilation error.
this `test.Id = 1;` will give compilation error as its readonly.

this `test.Dept = "CS";` is allowed.

this `test.LastName = "John";` is also not allowed, it will say set accessor not accessible.

this is allowed for init, not the one you have mentioned in your code.

```
public Test()
{
    DateOfJoining = "Today";
}
```

My class

```
internal class Test
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    //public string FirstName { get; readonly set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string DateOfJoining { get; init; }

    public Test()
    {
        DateOfJoining = "Today";
    }

}
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62372422/6527049) also for the difference between init and readonly. Init is to allow assignment in object initialization as well online the readonly.